# Unexpected behavior when an attribute is inherited with AllowMultiple = false

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, attributes

Let's say I have the following attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
class TestAttribute : Attribute { }

class FooAttribute : TestAttribute { }    
class BarAttribute : TestAttribute { }
```

I expect the attributes inherited from `TestAttribute` can't be duplicated for methods:

```
[Foo][Bar] //I expect compile error here
void M() { }
```

But in fact the `AllowMultiple` check is only applied in the same attribute type, means compile errors happen for `[Test][Test]`,`[Foo][Foo]`,`[Bar][Bar]`, but no error for `[Test][Foo]`,`[Foo][Bar]`.

It looks like by design than a bug? But with the definition of `TestAttribute` someone can easily make mistake like this:

```
//bang! why? AllowMultiple=false!
var testAttribute = someMethod.GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>();  
//or someMethod.GetCustomAttributes<TestAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
```

My questions are:

Q1: Why do they design it like this? I think my expected behavior is more "correct"?

Q2: Any workaround? I don't want to put Foo/Bar things to an enum and use something like `[Test(Flag=Foo)]`, because the inherited attributes have their different properties, putting them into one attribute is hard to maintain.

Comment: Hmm, Q1, it probably could be better at giving you more granular control over inheritance situations . i guess the only thing you can do is when reflecting the attributes pick the first of a base type (or pick your favourite!). i dont think you will be able to find a way to limit it

Comment: It is just not how AllowMultiple works, it is only checked at compile time. Avoid the "bang!" by simply using `GetCustomAttributes<TestAttribute>()` instead, now it can return multiple attributes without ambiguity.  But sure, this does not score any elegance points, reflection is not very elegant.